# Exception by migration from dagger to hilt

Tags: migration, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have exception

```
Exception is:
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Iterable initSteps()' of abstract class dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.
```

All

```
javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments['dagger.hilt.disableModulesHaveInstallInCheck'] = 'true'
```

and @DisableInstallInCheck annotation in @Module classes provided.